# Design a rounded corner layout with rounded image

Tags: android, layout, android-glide

I'm confused how to design the layout as shown below. I can do a circular image using glide but how to align it with the layout?

[image]

Regards,
Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the answers.

I found a solution with my UI goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_chip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/rv_profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/chip_pic_height_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/chip_pic_height_width"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
    app:riv_oval = "true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_half"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_half"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_half"
    android:textColor="@color/app_bg_white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    style="@style/SecondaryText"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_remove_circle_white_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_half"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_half"
    />

   </LinearLayout>
```

MY **background_chip** lookslike this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners
    android:radius="@dimen/chip_pic_radius"/>
<solid
    android:color="@color/grey_light"/>
```

Finally its looking like

[image]

Trick is I have given the corner radius exactly half as the width of my left image.

Answer (score 0):

Place a textview next to imageview. Both the imageview and textview should have background with rounded corners. You will need to work with your UX designer.

The textview and image view should have same height so that hey align correctly.